# Markov kernels between distributions

Tags: probability, coupling

Let $(P_i,Q_i)$ be couples of distributions, $i = 1,...n$. Suppose they share the same Markov kernel K, that is, $\forall i\in\{1,...n\}$ :
$$
Q_i(dy) = \int K(x,dy)P_i(dx)
$$

Now let $(X_i,Y_i)$ be a coupling with marginals $(P_i,Q_i)$ and conditional probability $K$.

Is there a function $h$ independent of i such the following equality holds in distribution for all i:
$$
Y_i = h(X_i)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the existence of such $h\ $ is not guaranteed even when $n=1$: For two given distributions $P,Q\ $ take $K=Q\ $ (independent of $x$) Then $(X,Y)$ is just the trivial coupling and $X,Y\ $ are independent so there is no such $h$.

Comment: Actually for any two random variables $X$ and $Y$ there always exists a measurable map $h$ such that $Y=h(X)$ in distribution. This is because $G(Y)$ and $F(X)$ are uniformly distributed over the interval [0,1] where $F$ and $G$ are the cdf's of $X$ and $Y$ respectively. Hence letting $h=G^{(-1)} \circ F$ insures that $Y = h(X)$ in distribution, where $G^{(-1)}$ is the generalized inverse of $G$.

Comment: Actually, your arguments in the comment above hold only in the case where $X,Y$ are random variables on the real line, otherwise the generalized inverse is not defined. A coupling is a pair of random variables defined on an abstract probability space, usually the product space, and may not be the real line.

Comment: Right, my bad, that assumption is missing. I am indeed only concerned with random variables taking values on the real line.